# Excluding NA and odd number

Tags: r, vector

Can anyone please share the R code to remove all NA and odd numbers from a vector.
For example, from this vector:
`x <- c(1, 4, NA, 7, 9, NA, 2)`

Comment: See this link: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-August/169636.html

Comment: What have you tried already? We are here to support you in finding your solution, not to give you free answers. Please, edit your post accordingly...

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you just have to keep numbers for which the remaining of a division by 2 is not 0. So, you can do this:

```r
x[which(x %% 2 == 0)]

[1] 4 2
```

Comment: This is keeping the odd numbers. Change that not equals to equals

Comment: @itslwg, you're right. I always confound two terms (I'm not a native english speaker)

Answer (score 3):

Use `is.na` to check for `NA` values and use the modulus to check for odd numbers:

```
x <- c(1, 4, NA, 7, 9, NA, 2)
x[!(is.na(x) | x %% 2 == 1)]

[1] 4 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
x <- c(1, 4, NA, 7, 9, NA, 2)
x <-x[!is.na(x) & x %% 2 == 0)]
```

Comment: Please explain the benefit over the existing upvoted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59113967/7733418 and why it is necessary or beneficial. This seems funcitonally very similar. What is the effect of the difference?